# How can I do branching in a SQL Server Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [TestId]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TestTypeID]     INT            NOT NULL,
    [ExamId]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [TestStatusId]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [TopicId]        INT            NOT NULL
);
```

I am using a Stored Procedure that I created for inserting data:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ins_test   
       @ExamId                          INT            ,
       @TestStatusId                    INT            ,
       @TestTypeId                      INT            ,
       @TopicId                         INT                           
AS 
BEGIN
```

How can I do a different action depending on the value of @TestTypeId ?

What I want to do is if the TestTypeId = 1 then I would like to update all test records that have TopicId = @TopicId and change the TestStatusId to 2.

If the TestTypeId = 2 then I would like to update all test records that have ExamId = @ExamId and change the TestStatusId to 2.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 UPDATE dbo.Test
 SET    TestStatusId = 2
 WHERE  TestTypeId = @TestTypeId
 AND    Title      = @Title;

 UPDATE dbo.Test
 SET    TestStatusId = 2
 WHERE  ExamId     = @ExamId
 AND    Title      = @Title;
```

However I am not sure how to select one or other update depending on the value of TestTypeId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ins_test   
       @ExamId                          INT            ,
       @TestStatusId                    INT            ,
       @TestTypeId                      INT            ,
       @TopicId                         INT                           
AS 
BEGIN 

 IF @TestTypeID = 1
    BEGIN

     UPDATE dbo.Test
     SET    TestStatusId = 2
     WHERE  TestTypeId = @TestTypeId
     AND    Title      = @Title;
    END

 IF @TestTypeId = 2
    BEGIN

     UPDATE dbo.Test
     SET    TestStatusId = 2
     WHERE  ExamId     = @ExamId
     AND    Title      = @Title;
    END

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can branch in SQL, and use `IF`, and `ELSE IF` blocks, but it's a good exercise to think in set based logic rather than procedural logic.

You can achieve this using more `WHERE` statements.

```
  update [Test]
  set TestStatusId = 2
  where TopicId = @TopicId
    and TestTypeID = 1

  update [Test]
  set TestStatusId = 2
  where ExamId = @ExamId
    and TestTypeID = 2
```

It's not entirely clear from your question

> What I want to do is if the TestTypeId = 1 then I would like to update
>   all test records that have TopicId = @TopicId and change the
>   TestStatusId to 2.

whether you are referring to TestTypeId column or @TestTypeId parameter, but you omitted the `@` so I am assuming you meant column.